# SQL to get json output in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to generate output from a table but I'm unable to get it.

```sql
create table t1(a int, b int, c text);
insert into t1 values (1, 1, 'm');
insert into t1 values (1, 2, 'm');
insert into t1 values (2, 7, 'm');
insert into t1 values (2, 8, 'n');
insert into t1 values (2, 9, 'o');

select array_to_json(array_arg(row_to_json(t)))
from (select a,b from t1)
```

I get this

```
[{'a':1, 'b':2'}, {'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':2,'b':7}, {'a':2, 'b':8}, {'a':2, 'b':9}]
```

Desired output

```
`[{'a':1, 'b':[1,2]}, {'a':2,'b': [7,8,9]}]`
```

Comment: Did you mean to `GROUP BY a`? That's not necessarily related to the JSON

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right lines! The following will do most of what you want:

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT a, array_agg(b) as b
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY a
    ORDER BY a
    )
SELECT json_agg(cte) 
FROM cte;
```

Whenever possible, use json_agg - it usually does what you want!

If you really want single quotes, then simply add a replace:

```
SELECT REPLACE(json_agg(cte)::text, '"', '''')
```

(Note that you have to escape the single quotes, as single quotes in SQL delineate a string.)

Comment: Thanks for the insight but this didn't get the desired result will play around

Answer (score 0):

I use the `jsonb` type instead of `json`.

Rather than deal with `text[]` array types, I would do the following:

```
with first_agg as (
  select a, jsonb_agg(b) as b
    from t1
   group by a
)
select to_jsonb(first_agg)
  from first_agg;
```

[Working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I__uUPbk)

Comment: Thanks for the insight but this didn't get the desired result will play around

Comment: @mvk859017 Surround it with `jsonb_agg()` like so:  https://dbfiddle.uk/yW4xeccL  Did you seriously not think to do that?

Comment: as said I will try and did try but it didn't come as expected so still trying with various options.

Comment: I was able to fix/figure out the issue.